# PHP Uploads Limit for Scanning?

Tags: php, file-upload

I read somewhere that the upload limit for php is about 2MBs. Does this still apply if I am asking a user to upload a file to the server to scan through and convert to a string? If so how do I get around this?

The application for this is a scanner type deal where users would be able to upload a code file, and this php application would scan through the code and look for certain comments to document and write to a documentation file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upload limits are configured in the php.ini file, see this: http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php

Yes it would apply to any file that is being uploaded by the user, regardless of what your server side app does with it. :)

The upload limit can be changed by modifying the settings in php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would (assuming it's a POST). You get around it by changing your php config.

PHP has two limits that apply in this case. Both are ini options: [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

I believe the upload_max_filesize defaults to 2 MB. (The post_max_size setting has to be larger than upload_max_filesize).

See: [Core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)